# Listview display nothing

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

`Listview` Size is 10 items. Till it does not display anything in `Listview`. I am adding List of Item in above adapter but not able to get the `Listview` single row. Anyone please help me to solve my error in the adapter?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import bughunters.tashfik.chooseapp.Model.Category;
import bughunters.tashfik.chooseapp.Model.Comment;
import bughunters.tashfik.chooseapp.R;
public class CommentViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

private List<Comment> messagesItems;


// public static List<String> imagelist;

public CommentViewAdapter(Context context, List<Comment> navDrawerItems) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Sixe ids"+String.valueOf(navDrawerItems.size()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    this.context = context;
    this.messagesItems = navDrawerItems;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messagesItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return messagesItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_list_item, null);

    TextView textViewProfileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfileName);
    TextView textViewMesssage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMesssage);
    TextView textViewTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    Toast.makeText(context,messagesItems.get(position).getUsername(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ImageView imageViewUserProfilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserProfilePic);


    textViewProfileName.setText(messagesItems.get(position).getUsername());
    textViewMesssage.setText(messagesItems.get(position).getMessage());
    textViewTime.setText(messagesItems.get(position).getTime());


    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you also post the comments_list_item.xml file?

Comment: can you post MainActivity File?

Comment: Please post your Activity's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below code:-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import bughunters.tashfik.chooseapp.Model.Category;
import bughunters.tashfik.chooseapp.Model.Comment;
import bughunters.tashfik.chooseapp.R;
public class CommentViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

private List<Comment> messagesItems;


// public static List<String> imagelist;

public CommentViewAdapter(Context context, List<Comment> navDrawerItems) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Sixe ids"+String.valueOf(navDrawerItems.size()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    this.context = context;
    this.messagesItems = navDrawerItems;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messagesItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return messagesItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_list_item, null,true);

    TextView textViewProfileName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfileName);
    TextView textViewMesssage = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMesssage);
    TextView textViewTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

    ImageView imageViewUserProfilePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserProfilePic);

    textViewProfileName.setText(messagesItems.get(position).getUsername());
    textViewMesssage.setText(messagesItems.get(position).getMessage());
    textViewTime.setText(messagesItems.get(position).getTime());

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Check your MainActivity code with below code:-

```
CommentViewAdapter customAdapter = new CommentViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), levelLists(your ArrayList Put here));
  listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```